# Suppose (X,Y) have a Dirichlet ($a_1, a_2, a_3$)distribution.

Tags: probability

> The joint density of (X,Y) is $f_{x,y}(x,y)={\Gamma(a_1,a_2,a_3)\over \Gamma(a_1)\Gamma(a_2)\Gamma(a_3)} x^{a_1-1}y^{a_2-2}(1-x-y)^{a_3-1}$ where $x\ge0$ 
> $y\ge0$ and $x+y \le1$  and o otherwise
>
> a) find the marginal densities of x and y, are x and y independent?
>
>  b)let $U= {x\over x+y}$ find the density of U. Identify the distribution of U by name and specify all parameter values.

for a, I tried to do the integral f(x)dy and f(y)dx but i find it very complicated, is there any trick to this?
and would like any help with b as well

thank you very much!

Comment: Homework?  If so, identify it as such.

Comment: Sorry! has put it back on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f_X(x)=\int_0^{1-x}Cx^{a_1-1}y^{a_2-1}(1-x-y)^{a_3-1}dy = Cx^{a_1-1}\int_0^{1-x}y^{a_2-1}(1-x-y)^{a_3-1}dy$.  Make a change of variable to convert the latter integral into one you know.